# How to work with a single cmd output and disregard the other output

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, output

Trying to write a batch file that can extract a single output from a command that delivers many outputs and pass it to a variable so that I can work with it. While I have many projects that I would like to use this technique for, one example is executing the netsh wlan show drivers, and writing only the Radio Types Supported output to a variable, so that I can search for various types and make the program respond accordingly.

For example, from this output, I want to extract only Radio Types Supported:

```
C:\Users\brent>netsh wlan show drivers

Interface name: Wi-Fi

Driver                    : Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
Vendor                    : Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Provider                  : Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Date                      : 5/18/2017
Version                   : 2023.55.415.2017
INF file                  : oem7.inf
Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
Radio types supported     : 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b 802.11ac 802.11n 802.11a
FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
Hosted network supported  : No
Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                            Open            None
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                            WPA-Personal    TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                            WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                            WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                            WPA-Personal    CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                            Vendor defined  TKIP
                            Vendor defined  CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
IHV service present       : Yes
IHV adapter OUI           : [00 e0 4c], type: [00]
IHV extensibility DLL path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Rtlihvs.dll
IHV UI extensibility ClSID: {6c2a8cca-b2a2-4d81-a3b2-4e15f445c312}
IHV diagnostics CLSID     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Wireless Display Supported: No (Graphics Driver: No, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

Something like this, even though this is obviously defective code:

```
Set FOO=netsh wlan show drivers{Radio Types Supported}
echo %FOO%

::Desired Output
802.11n 802.11g 802.11b 802.11ac 802.11n 802.11a
```

I tried some Google sleuthing before writing this, but I cannot seem to find an answer that is suitable.

Comment: What about `grep` or `findstr`?

Comment: I think that findstr is the hot ticket. Thanks!

Comment: The irony in your question is that you said you couldn't `FIND` an answer, when you could use the `FIND` command to do what you wanted to do. You also stated in your question that you wanted the output assigned to a variable but the answer you accepted does not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use findstr, if I am not wrong

```
netsh wlan show drivers | findstr Radio
```

Comment: You beat me with one second :-)

Comment: hahaha I checked in local cmd prompt and then answered here :)

Comment: This answer does not address the second part of the question.  You still need to assign the output to a variable as shown in [Stephan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54437377/1417694).

Answer (score 0):

To filter for a specific line, use `find` or `findstr`:

```
netsh wlan show drivers |find "Radio types supported"
```

to get the output of a command to a variable, use a `for /f` loop around:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show drivers ^|find "Radio types supported"') do set "rtypes=%%a"
echo %rtypes%
```